# How to change favicon in a secure site

Tags: force.com-sites, favicon

I have set a custom favicon on a Force.com site, but it is only working on the public site. The secure site still displays the default Salesforce favicon.

`<mycompany>.force.com/favicon.ico` is the custom favicon, but `<mycompany>.secure.force.com/favicon.ico` is the standard SF favicon.

From [this question](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000009A6PIAU) in the SF discussion forums, I understand that the custom favicon should take affect in a secure site if the site has no path. Yet, it is not working in our case.

For now, I'm adding `<link rel="icon" href="{!$Resource.Favicon}" />` to the site template. However, I would prefer to do it declaratively if possible.

Comment: in the past i have seen this behavior, but for some reason it took a day or two to 'take effect'. I would add the favicon, and it wouldnt show like you said, but then a day or so later it was there. This was a few years ago, but i am wondering if it is still the case now.

Comment: Hi Geeljire, I am sure you must have already did but trying luck ;) Did you tried any other browser which didnt opened that website or tried to clean all your cookies ? basically in my case I cleared cookies and all data and it started showing up.

Answer (score 1):

We did this, and the favicon used by the site config page in salesforce works for both public and secure URLs...nothing extra to do there.

I didn't add the favicon on the site template.

I'd suggest giving it a few days.  Is your site new, or just the favicon?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var myvar  = '<title>Sample Title</title>';
        myvar +='<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.favicon)}" type="image/png" />';

        $('head').append(myvar);

    })
</script>
```